# How can I get hidden byproducts from the results?

Tags: python, inspect

It's hard to search because I can't even figure out how to refer it.

I used R before, so let me give an example.

Say you did a linear regression.

[image]

As you can watch above, `lm1` only shows the partial results but using `names()` function, you can list all the byproducts of the result. 
So you can explicitly call it with `lm1$coefficients`, `lm1$residuals`, ...

What is the corresponding function in python?

I used `inspect.getmembers` so far, but maybe expecting some other functions.

You can edit this context in relevant wording, if there exists.

Comment: `inspect.getmembers` sounds like the right idea. You could also use `dir()` for just the names, overall the result will be similar. What do you mean by "but maybe expecting some other functions"? Python isn't R, it has different functions. What are you inspecting, what did you find, and what were you expecting?

Comment: @AlexHall For example, when I crawling, I use `import requests` then, `request` module has a lot of functions.
Which I can access the list using `inspect.getmebers`. But, say I did `response = requests.get('some_url')`. Then how can I know all the attributes of this `response`?
Still with `inspect.getmembers`? It doesn't show that `response.text` is available.

Comment: Yes it does. `import inspect, requests; response = requests.get("http://xkcd.com"); members = inspect.getmembers(response); assert dict(members)["text"] == response.text`

Comment: @AlexHall I should have looked carefully. Thanks!